# OWA website down in sbs2003

Tags: iis, windows-sbs-2003, outlook-web-app

Suddenly and inexplicably the Outlook Web Access site on one of the SBS 2003 sites I manage is down. To my knowledge, nothing has changed on the server and we've rebooted it to see if the site comes back up. It doesn't.

It doesn't work from inside or outside the network. Web browsers give a "cannot display the web page" style error. The most information I've been able to glean is from Chrome which states: Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): Unknown error. I don't know if that's a false clue however.

I have very limited (read: none) skills at troubleshooting IIS. Can anyone point out some useful tips?

Cheers,

Mike...

Comment: Do you call the site using ISA Server as web proxy? http://www.edugeek.net/forums/internet-related-filtering-firewall/47614-isa-2006-ie7-ssl-problems.html

Comment: No, I don't. No ISA here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a problem with the certificate associated to the OWA web site. Can you check the certificate on that server?

Comment: I can. How shall I do it? :)

Comment: Oh wow. That was it. I checked the assigned cert on the Default Web Site and it was missing. I reassigned it and all is okay. Whew! Thanks!